# Uniqueness of Categorical Equivalences

Tags: category-theory, functors

For two categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, and a functor $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$, can there exist two distinct (there does not exist a natural isomorphism between them) fucntors $G,G': \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ such that the pairs $(F,G)$ and $(F,G')$ are both equivalences?

Comment: Nope. Inverses are unique up to equivalence. This follows e.g. from the fact that inverses are adjoints (on both sides).

Comment: The comment by @QiaochuYuan is correct, but you don't need adjoints. You just need that composition preserves natural isomorphism (and that composition is associative). Then you have $G'=G'1\cong G'FG\cong1G=G$.